# Combining unobtrusive JavaScript with Pusher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, real-time, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm using [Pusher](http://pusher.com/docs/quickstart) to add real-time page updates to my Rails app.

Here's a brief synopsis of how Pusher works (and later I'll show you what I'd like it to do):

Controller:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @thing = Thing.new(params[:thing])

    if @thing.save
      Pusher['things'].trigger('thing-create', @thing.attributes)
    end
  end
end
```

Javascript (in `<head>...</head>`):

```
var pusher = new Pusher('API_KEY');
var myChannel = pusher.subscribe('MY_CHANNEL');
myChannel.bind('thing-create', function(thing) {
  alert('A thing was created: ' + thing.name); // I want to replace this line
});
```

I want to replace the commented line with an ajax request to trigger some unobtrusive JavaScript. Assume I have the file app/views/things/index.js.erb:

```
$("things").update("<%= escape_javascript(render(@things))%>");
```

What should I write in the myChannel.bind callback to trigger the above code to execute?

Comment: Are you creating a `Thing` via AJAX? Or just a standard HTTP request?

Comment: hey, i just went though this after reading your multiple questions and wrote an answer just for you. Check my answer posted below. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @joel, I'll take a look and comment later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not really comparing apples-to-apples here.

You are comparing the template rendered in an XHR request to `things/index` to the attributes of the `@thing` object from a POST to `things/create`.

You need to process the `thing` object that gets returned from Pusher in the web browser and modify the DOM accordingly.

Or, an easier solution would probably be to have your controller send formatted HTML to Pusher instead of object attributes.  Then your javascript code could just insert the formatted HTML instead of trying to parse the `thing` object and modify the DOM manually.

---

Response to @user94154's comment:

DISCLAIMER:  I never heard of Pusher until your question.

This does create a challenge b/c typically your HTML is formatted in the view, but you have to send data to Pusher from the controller.  I can think of a few ways to do this:

1. If it isn't much HTML markup, you might want to break the "Don't Repeat Yourself" rule and repeat the HTML markup in your controller and send that to Pusher
2. If it is a lot of markup, I would abstract my view generation code to helpers.  You can call a helper from your controller, too.

On the client side, you should have an empty div (or some DOM element) that can hold the HTML from Pusher.  And do something like this:

```
myChannel.bind('thing-create', function(thing) {
  $("div#thing_holder").html(thing.html);
});
```

Comment: How do I do that last option, where the client makes an ajax call to the server, and gets back html from a specific partial in the response?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Option 1 doesn't answer my question--I know that by repeating myself, I can solve this pretty easily (for the short term at least). So regarding option 2, you're saying I get the empty HTML from a helper in my controller, send it to a template, then fill in the content with the Pusher callback?

Comment: No, the helper method(s) provide formatted HTML, which your controller and view use.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2010/5/12/integrating-pusher-into-a-complex-app-in-one-day

A little over my head, but I think it may put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

[pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) might be what you are looking for. Included in the README is how to get started with it in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, here is how you do it...

Tried writing it on here but the code indenting, etc doesn't work well for longer stuff...

http://jbeas.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-3-pusher-app-and-unobtrusive-js/